# Meteor, Error: Can't wait without a fiber using Meteor.setTimeout() on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm fairly new to Meteor so I might be missing a key insight here.

Anyway, I want to indicate to users how many other users is on the site at the same time. I have an `AuditItems` collection already that stores kv-pairs for `who`, `when` and `what` that I can use for this type of computation. My `Collections` query is run with a `new Date()` parameter so I can't just observe the results, I have to rerun the query periodically.

I then *made* it reactive by calling `changed` on a `Deps.Dependency`.

Here is the code:

```
  // publishing counts of the users that are logged on
  // at the moment
  Meteor.publish("user-activity", function () {
    var self = this;

    self.added("user-activity", "all-recent-activity", {'operations': getRecentActivityCountsCache});
    self.ready();

    Deps.autorun(function() {
      self.changed("user-activity", "all-recent-activity", {'operations': getRecentActivityCounts()});
    });
  });

  var getRecentActiveCountsDependency = new Deps.Dependency;
  var getRecentActivityCountsCache = 0;
  var getRecentActivityCounts = function() {

    // register dependency with the caller
    getRecentActiveCountsDependency.depend();

    var now = new Date();
    var aWhileAgo = new Date(now.valueOf() - (5 * 60 * 1000)); // 5 minutes

    auditItems = AuditItems.find({'when': { '$gt': aWhileAgo }}).fetch();

    console.log('raw data: ' + JSON.stringify(auditItems));

    getRecentActivityCountsCache = _.chain(auditItems)
      .groupBy('who')
      .keys()
      .size()
      .value();

    console.log('new count: ' + getRecentActivityCountsCache);

    return getRecentActivityCountsCache;
  };

  Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
    getRecentActiveCountsDependency.changed();
  }, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds
```

I am getting this error on the console the first time the timer fires:

```
    Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Can't wait without a fiber
        at Function.wait (/home/vagrant/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:83:9)
        at Object.Future.wait (/home/vagrant/.meteor/tools/3cba50c44a/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:325:10)
        at _.extend._nextObject (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:540)
        at _.extend.forEach (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:570)
        at _.extend.map (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:582)
        at _.extend.fetch (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:606)
        at _.each.Cursor.(anonymous function) [as fetch] (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:444)
        at getRecentActivityCounts (app/server/server.js:26:70)
        at null._func (app/server/server.js:12:79)
        at _.extend._compute (packages/deps/deps.js:129)
```

Answer (score 2):

All the `Deps` methods can only be used on the [Client](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps). The error you get is around the way Deps was built (since the client doesn't use fibers).

If you want to have reactivity on the server you need to use [`observe`](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) or `observeChanges`. Using the added and removed handle & you could query the date at that point (when the document changes).

You could also use `Meteor.setInterval` to periodically remove the older users from there.

One of the things you could do is use a package like [meteor-prescence](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-presence) which does it all for you. What it does is it holds a live collection containing info on everyone who is online, then when they go offline/after a timeout it removes them from the collection using a periodic `Meteor.setInterval` method.